# Android Studio - Manually installing repository dependencies or updates

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.3

When I open Android Studio and select to choose the SDK location, the program requests me to download missing or outdated resources.

Then starts a download from dl.google.com/android/repository , this time gms and wearable libs. However, my computer is under a proxy and even when I setup the proxy the download always fails when downloading from Android Studio.

However, I did manually download the zip directly from the URL and zip was downloaded OK.

Where do I need to place those files into the Android data in order to complete installation? I looked inside `AppData/AndroidStudio/SDK` but the directory structure is different:

Android Studio directory:

```
Android / SDK / extras / android / m2repositori / com / android 
      databinding
      support
         bunch of libraries
         wearable
             metadatas
             26.0.0-alpha1
```

The downloaded zip contains:

```
m2repository / com / google
       android
             gms
             support
             wearable
                 wearable
       firebase
             bunch of firebase folders
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it was dumb, the correct repository was

```
Android / Sdk / extras / google / m2repository
```

I needed also to add a package.xml from another Windows computer which contains the terms and conditions, not sure if it is really needed for the Studio to recognize the installed files.